# How do I sed/grep the last word in a filename?

Tags: bash, sed, grep, busybox

I have a couple of filenames for different languages. I need to grep or sed just the language part. I am using `gconftool-2 -R /` and want to pipe a command to bring out just the letters with the language.

```
active = file.so,sv.xml
active = file.so,en_GB.xml
active = file.so,en_US.xml
```

I need the `sv` and `en_GB` part of the file. How can I do that in the most effective way? I am thinking of something like `gconftool-2 -R / | sed -n -e '/active =/p̈́' -e '/\.$/'` but then I get stuck as I don't know how to print just the part I need and not the whole line.

Comment: Have updated the answer based on the new input. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using simple `cut`

```
cut -d. -f3 filename
```

**Test:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat filename
active = file.so.sv.xml
active = file.so.en_GB.xml
active = file.so.en_US.xml

[jaypal:~/Temp] cut -d. -f3 filename
sv
en_GB
en_US
```

**Based on the updated input:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat filename
active = file.so,sv.xml
active = file.so,en_GB.xml
active = file.so,en_US.xml

[jaypal:~/Temp] cut -d, -f2 filename | sed 's/\..*//g'
sv
en_GB
en_US
```

**OR**

**Using `awk`:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F[,.] '{print $3}' filename
sv
en_GB
en_US

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -F[,.] '{print $(NF-1)}' filename
sv
en_GB
en_US
```

**OR**

**Using `grep` and `tr`:**

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] egrep -o ",\<.[^\.]*\>" f | tr -d ,
sv
en_GB
en_US
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Should have been more observant on the `,`. ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F. '{print $(NF-1)}'
```

NF is the number of fields, awk counts from 1 so the 2nd to last field is NF-1.
The -F. says that fields are separated by "." rather than whitespace

Comment: Ah yes, awk... BTW you could add `/^active =/` since the OP filters with that as well in `sed`. Nice one!

Comment: @fge - awk always seems simpler (more 'C' like) than sed. Might be different if you are a perl/lisp type

Comment: @fge - the active part shouldn't matter because we are counting fields from the end

Comment: @MartinBeckett Your solution was the most elegant.. but i just noticed that it has `,` instead of `.` of some reason. So it should be `active = file.so,en_GB.xml`. Sorry for the misspelling. Am using a very small text size.

Comment: @AlNehdi - see JayPal's answer for how to modify it

Answer (score 1):

`awk` would be my main tool for this task but since that has already been proposed, I'll add a solution using `cut` instead

```
cut -d. -f3
```

i.e. use `.` as delimiter and select the third field.

Since you tagged the question with `bash`, I'll add a pure bash solution as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash 

IFS=.

while read -a LINE;
do
    echo ${LINE[2]}
done < file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`gconftool-2 -R / | grep '^active = ' | sed 's,\.[^.]\+$,,; s,.*\.,,'`

The first `sed` command says to remove a dot followed by everything not a dot until the end of line; the second one says to remove everything until the last dot.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
gconftool-2 -R / | sed -n 's/^active.*,\([^.]*\).*/\1/p'
```